# Select a QComboBox using QtWebdriver

Tags: python, qt, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I select the item of a `QtComboBox`? The `Select` statement doesn't like the `QtComboBox`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Remote(...)

myComboBox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//QComboBox[@id='aComboBox']")[0]
select = Select(privLevelCBox)


UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <QComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Select` statement is made for the html `select` tag. So it's obvious that this doesn't work. But the solution to select a specific item is to use `send_keys(...)`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Remote(...)

myComboBox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//QComboBox[@id='aComboBox']")[0]
myComboBox.send_keys("label")
```